# It says it cant find the current file but it still prints it out that its there

Tags: python, excel, loops, xlsx

I am trying to run a program that will go through all of my excel files in my folder and remove the empty rows.
When I try running it, I get an error that says that my current file in the loop isn't found. 
I tried printing out the current file in the loop and it printed out that it is there. 

Why isn't it working?
As you can see in the error screenshot, it prints out the name of the current file but then later it says it can't find it. 
Please help

```
import os
from spire.xls import *
from spire.common import *

#directory that needs to get fixed:
path = 'C:/Users/paulina.rios/Desktop/Teacher Sheets - Copy (2) - Copy/'

#creates a list with directory file names
list = os.listdir(path)

# Goes through each file in the directory
for file in list:
    print(file)

  # Specify the input and output file paths
    inputFile = file
    outputFile = "Edited.xlsx"

  # Create a workbook instance
    workbook = Workbook()

  # Load an Excel file
    workbook.LoadFromFile(inputFile)

  # Get the first worksheet
    sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]

  # Delete blank rows from the worksheet
    for i in range(sheet.Rows.Length - 1, -1, -1):
        if sheet.Rows[i].IsBlank:
            sheet.DeleteRow(i + 1)

# Save the result file
    workbook.SaveToFile(outputFile, ExcelVersion.Version2013)
    workbook.Dispose()
```

Here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk5km.png):

```
C:\Users\paulina.rios\PycharmProjects\python Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\paulina.rios\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\this one.py"
10175.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\paulina.rios\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\this one.py", line 24, in <module>
    workbook.LoadFromFile(inputFile)
  File "C:\Users\paulina.rios\PycharmProjects\python Project\venv\lib\site-packages\plum\function.py", line 642, in __call__ 
    return self.f(self.instance, *args, **kw_args)
  File "C:\Users\paulina.rios\PycharmProjects\python Project\venv\lib\site-packages\plum\function.py", line 592, in __call__ 
    return _convert (method (*args, **kw_args), return_type)
  File "C:\Users\paulina.rios\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\spire\xls\Workbook.py", line 602, in LoadFromFile 
    raise ArgumentError(intPtr.typeName)
ctypes. ArgumentError: IO_FileNotFound_FileName, C:\Users\paulina.rios\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\10175.xlsx

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am new to Python.

Comment: Please share your code and error as text

Comment: In the [docs](https://www.e-iceblue.com/apireference/net/Spire.XLS/html/Overload_Spire_Xls_Workbook_LoadFromFile.htm) it looks like for the `LoadFromFile` method you can specify the ExcelVersion and Encoding. I wonder if the version of Excel you're using or the encoding of the spreadsheet isn't right for that file.

Comment: The path in the error and the path in your code are completely different; what's up with that?

Comment: Also, just a tip, you could try using the Pandas library for this instead. Read the excel file into a dataframe via `pandas.read_excel`, then call `drop_na` on the dataframe and save it back to an excel file via `to_excel`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html. 

Might be easier than the library you're using and might not throw the same issue.

Comment: List would be only the filenames in the given directory, i.e. not the path just the name like '10175.xlsx'. The load of the workbook is `workbook.LoadFromFile(inputFile)` and inputFile is going to just be that filename. Therefore it seems reasonable that the code would not be able to find the file. I'd suggest you change the line `inputFile = file` to `inputFile = os.path.join(path,file)` so the workbook has the full path to the file.

Comment: Also all the file are being saved as "Edited.xlsx" in the same directory so you'd end up with one file called "Edited.xlsx" being the last edited file. These will also be saved in the directory where the code runs since again there is no path.

Answer (score 0):

The items in the list are the names of the Excel files not their full paths. You should change your code like this:

```
#directory that needs to get fixed:
path = 'C:/Users/paulina.rios/Desktop/Teacher Sheets - Copy (2) - Copy/'

#creates a list with directory file names
list = os.listdir(path)

# Goes through each file in the directory
for file in list:
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    # Create a workbook instance
    workbook = Workbook()
    # Load an Excel file
    workbook.LoadFromFile(file_path)
    # .......
```